# I have an issue with setting up coreui admin template

Tags: css, laravel, npm, core-ui

my issue is that I tried different methods of using this theme without any success

1- I followed the steps in the documentation as I clone the repo of the template then npm instal (npm run serve) -> never works with me and I used the CDN I tried multiple times with both bootstrap template and laravel template as my project is based on laravel but I'm trying the template in a new template

2- I saw a tutorial on youtube by (laravel daily) and he used the starter template so I also gave it a try but still the css isn't working

this is my code for app.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CoreUI CSS -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
</head>
<body class="c-app">

@include('partials.menu')
@yield('content')

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- Popper.js first, then CoreUI JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/js/coreui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the home page code

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
{{-- <base href="{{ \URL::to('/')}}"> --}}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {{ __('You are logged in!') }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and this is the sidebar file which is in partials->menu.blade.php

```
<div class="c-sidebar c-sidebar-dark c-sidebar-fixed c-sidebar-lg-show" id="sidebar">
    <div class="c-sidebar-brand d-lg-down-none">
        <svg class="c-sidebar-brand-full" width="118" height="46" alt="CoreUI Logo">
            <use xlink:href="assets/brand/coreui.svg#full"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg class="c-sidebar-brand-minimized" width="46" height="46" alt="CoreUI Logo">
            <use xlink:href="assets/brand/coreui.svg#signet"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <ul class="c-sidebar-nav">
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="index.html">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-speedometer"></use>
                </svg> Dashboard<span class="badge badge-info">NEW</span></a></li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-title">Theme</li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="colors.html">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-drop"></use>
                </svg> Colors</a></li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="typography.html">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-pencil"></use>
                </svg> Typography</a></li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-title">Components</li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link c-sidebar-nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-puzzle"></use>
                </svg> Base</a>
            <ul class="c-sidebar-nav-dropdown-items">
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/breadcrumb.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Breadcrumb</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/cards.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Cards</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/carousel.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Carousel</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/collapse.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Collapse</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/forms.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Forms</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/jumbotron.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Jumbotron</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/list-group.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> List group</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/navs.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Navs</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/pagination.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Pagination</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/popovers.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Popovers</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/progress.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Progress</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/scrollspy.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Scrollspy</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/switches.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Switches</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/tables.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Tables</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/tabs.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Tabs</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="base/tooltips.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Tooltips</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link c-sidebar-nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-cursor"></use>
                </svg> Buttons</a>
            <ul class="c-sidebar-nav-dropdown-items">
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="buttons/buttons.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Buttons</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="buttons/button-group.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Buttons Group</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="buttons/dropdowns.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Dropdowns</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="buttons/brand-buttons.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Brand Buttons</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="charts.html">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-chart-pie"></use>
                </svg> Charts</a></li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-dropdown"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-star"></use>
                </svg> Icons</a>
            <ul class="c-sidebar-nav-dropdown-items">
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="icons/coreui-icons-free.html"> CoreUI Icons<span class="badge badge-success">Free</span></a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="icons/coreui-icons-brand.html"> CoreUI Icons - Brand</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="icons/coreui-icons-flag.html"> CoreUI Icons - Flag</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link c-sidebar-nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-bell"></use>
                </svg> Notifications</a>
            <ul class="c-sidebar-nav-dropdown-items">
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="notifications/alerts.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Alerts</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="notifications/badge.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Badge</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="notifications/modals.html"><span class="c-sidebar-nav-icon"></span> Modals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="widgets.html">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-calculator"></use>
                </svg> Widgets<span class="badge badge-info">NEW</span></a></li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-divider"></li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-title">Extras</li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item c-sidebar-nav-dropdown"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link c-sidebar-nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-star"></use>
                </svg> Pages</a>
            <ul class="c-sidebar-nav-dropdown-items">
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="login.html" target="_top">
                        <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                            <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-account-logout"></use>
                        </svg> Login</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="register.html" target="_top">
                        <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                            <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-account-logout"></use>
                        </svg> Register</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="404.html" target="_top">
                        <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                            <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-bug"></use>
                        </svg> Error 404</a></li>
                <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="500.html" target="_top">
                        <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                            <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-bug"></use>
                        </svg> Error 500</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item mt-auto"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link c-sidebar-nav-link-success" href="https://coreui.io" target="_top">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-cloud-download"></use>
                </svg> Download CoreUI</a></li>
        <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item"><a class="c-sidebar-nav-link c-sidebar-nav-link-danger" href="https://coreui.io/pro/" target="_top">
                <svg class="c-sidebar-nav-icon">
                    <use xlink:href="vendors/@coreui/icons/svg/free.svg#cil-layers"></use>
                </svg> Try CoreUI<strong>PRO</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="c-sidebar-minimizer c-class-toggler" type="button" data-target="_parent" data-class="c-sidebar-minimized"></button>
</div>
```

and this is the output I'm getting

[Image of the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAlcq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the vue version with npm and it works (even if you don't want to use vue).

1. `npm install`
2. Add `@import '@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css';` (and any
   other required css file) to resources/css/app.css
3. Do the same for js files

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow the instructions to install the git repo
2. `npm install`
3. `npm start`
4. This will show you the compiled version on port 3000
5. open this file: \coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template-main\dist\index.html
6. Replace "node_modules/" with "../node_modules/"
7. Now double click the index.html file to open normally. You should see the Admin Template properly. You need to fix the icons now.
8. Read the following: [http://glivera-team.github.io/svg/2019/03/15/svg-sprites-2.en.html]